# Mongodb update a particular word in a string in a multiple document

Tags: python, mongodb

I am updating a `mongodb` collection for a small project of mine and I'm stuck with updating a single word in an existing field.

Example:

```json
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5faa46a6036e146f85a4afef"),
   "name" : "Kubernetes_cluster_setup - kubernetes-cluster"
}
```

- In the document I want to change the `"name": "Kubernetes_cluster_config -kubernetes-cluster"`.
- I want config to be replaced in place of setup, and it should not remove the -kubernetes-cluster, that is a constant value.

Applied method > `$set` updates the entire field, but I want -kubernetes-cluster should not be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`$replaceOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/) operator.

You need an aggregation like this.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "name": {
        "$replaceOne": {
          "input": "$name",
          "find": "setup",
          "replacement": "config"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The first part is to find the element (I've used by `id`) and the second one is used to replace into the field `name`, the value `setup` for `config`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DuVPpIOd8l6)

Also, if you want to replace the string for every document, you can use this query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": {
        "$regex": "setup"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "name": {
        "$replaceOne": {
          "input": "$name",
          "find": "setup",
          "replacement": "config"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here the query look for the documents where field `name` contains the word `setup` and then replace for `config`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rwZ-5RM_uHl)

Comment: Thanks J.F. This actually solved my problem in the local environment which is running mongo version 4.4, but in my aws vm the mongo version 3.4 and when I run the same query there it gives this error Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) `$set` is not included as aggregation stage in version 3.4. Try using `$addFields` instead of `$set`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!.. $addFields is also not working for 3.4 version.. Need to find a new workaround.